# Getting cross-platform embed code from Open Graph meta

Tags: facebook, cross-browser, cross-platform, facebook-opengraph, video-embedding

I notice that the og:video properties in the open graph protocol are mainly SWF files. Site's like Youtube and Vimeo have players that work on mobile (that is, if I use an iframe element and their embed URLs). But, if I use the open graph protocol, I'll be limited to using the SWF format. Why doesn't the open graph meta contain the URL to use for an iframe's src attribute?

Is there a way to get a cross-platform (mobile-friendly) URL for a video/music player (for Youtube, Vimeo, SoundCloud, etc)?